# Meteor: bundled package cannot generate pdf

Tags: node.js, meteor

In the non bundled meteor app, I generate a file to app/.pdfs/2342834234.pdf and then serve this file to the user.

In the bundled meteor app, it is not able to create a pdf in that directory. I have enabled chmod 777 on the .pdfs directory but it's unable to write to that file.

```
function downloadAndSavePdf(fileUrl, fileName, callback) {                                                   
  return request(fileUrl, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(error + " " + response + " " + body);// 65
    if (error)                                                                                               
      callback(error);                                                                                       
    if (response.statusCode !== 200)                                                                         
      callback((new Meteor.Error(500, "Failed to fetch pdf from")));                                         
  }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(getPath() + '/.pdfs/' + fileName));                                           
}
```

`downloadAndSavePdf()` returns a `Writeable Stream` object which throws error. When I look into /.pdfs/ there's nothing there. Usually, the pdf generated

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path, what does getPath() return? Is it relative?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read somewhere that meteor.com provides local file storage?  Few paas sites do, which led me to abandon sqlite.  It may accept the chmod but still be a read only dest.